# Error while making datasource in tomcat conf folder and connecting with spring and hibernate

Tags: spring, database-connection, datasource

We are getting error while connecting spring and hibernate with tomcat datasource 
please suggest what to do

I had checked many configration files and spring jee jndi resource but nothing to find.

Is there any special way to connect it

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDat
aSource.java:1143)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSo
urce.java:880)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflecti
on(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynami
cAopProxy.java:196)
        at $Proxy9.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.
getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:
84)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073
)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.jav
a:1298)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(Annotat
ionConfiguration.java:859)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSession
Factory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessi
onFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPr
opertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:767)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.
java:559)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject
(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:283)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:767)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.j
ava:478)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject
(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:283)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:767)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.j
ava:478)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject
(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:283)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
        at org.springframeorg.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactio
nException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception i
s org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegi
n(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionMa
nager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.
createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:354)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.in
voke(TransactionInterceptor.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynami
cAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy21.getProducts(Unknown Source)
        at com.max.premcalc.service.CalcServiceImpl.getProducts(CalcServiceImpl.
java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflecti
on(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJo
inpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.in
voke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynami
cAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy23.getProducts(Unknown Source)
        at com.max.premcalc.controller.MainController.getRegisterForm(MainContro
ller.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.
doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.
invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandle
rAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandle
rAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:771)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl
et.java:552)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:263)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:584)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:44
7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException
(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.j
ava:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelp
er.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelp
er.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager
.java:426)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.
java:144)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:
57)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326
)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegi
n(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC dr
iver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDat
aSource.java:1150)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSo
urce.java:880)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflecti
on(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynami
cAopProxy.java:196)
        at $Proxy9.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.
getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager
.java:423)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDat
aSource.java:1143)
        ... 60 more
```

Comment: Could you show the configuration code of your datasource

Comment: <Context>
     <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource><Resource name="inquizzitiveds" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="com.max.premcalc.utils.DataSource"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.23.51.195:1875:TPPSIT"
          username="INQSIT" password="L5JyJukb8gI=" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="-1" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
         testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="true" validationQuery="select 'validationQuery' from dual"/> 

</Context>

Comment: I meant your spring config (btw, you posted the password of your database:-)  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,Let me complete the above answer,along with this

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
   jndi-name="name_of_your_datasource"
   expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

you have to configure your server.xml like this :-

```
     <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
    factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory" maxActive="20" 
maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/oracleDS" password="your pasword" 
type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" url="your jdbc URL" user="your username"/>.
```

And I hope it will work fine.Feel free to reach me anytime.Sunil

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.max.premcalc.service.CalcService com.max.premcalc.controller.MainController.calcService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calcServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Comment: Please post your complete spring-context.xml so it would be better to answer.

Comment: Iam pasting it in breakups

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.max.premcalc" />

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

Comment: <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/inquizzitiveds" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

Comment: <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.max.premcalc.domain.PremiumCalc</value>
    <value>com.max.premcalc.domain.Inputparam</value>
    <value>com.max.premcalc.domain.RiderInput</value>
    <value>com.max.premcalc.domain.Rider</value>
    <value>com.max.premcalc.domain.Product</value>
    <value>com.max.premcalc.domain.Products</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">

Comment: <props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
</props></property></bean><bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"><property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/></bean><bean id="calcDao" class="com.max.premcalc.dao.CalcDaoImpl"/><bean id="calcService" class="com.max.premcalc.service.CalcServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="inputparam" class="com.max.premcalc.domain.Inputparam"/></beans>

Comment: Sorry this is due to Large file i had break it.

Comment: Okay I got your problem.I think in server.xml you have to change datasource attribute according to the your SQL database and i given oracle datasource.

Comment: <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    factory="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" 
maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/inquizzitiveds" password="your pasword" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="your jdbc URL" user="your username"/>.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this in your spring context.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
   jndi-name="name_of_your_datasource"
   expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```